# If nonempty, finite $U,V \subseteq R^n$, then $\operatorname{span}(U)+\operatorname{span}(V) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(U \cup V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let me try and prove it. Suppose $U=\{u_i:i \in \mathbb N\}$ and $V=\{v_i:i \in \mathbb N\}$. Then $\operatorname{span}(U)+\operatorname{span}(V)= \left\{\sum_{i = 1}^k(a_iu_i+b_iv_i)\right\}$. Since $U \cup V$ contains $u_i,v_i$ $\operatorname{span}(U \cup V)$ contains the set of all $a_iu_i+b_iv_i.$

Does this work?

Comment: How do you *define* $\operatorname{span}(U) + \operatorname{span}(V)$ if not as $\operatorname{span}(U \cup V)$?

Comment: @ A.P., Unfortunately, the relation is not given as a definition, so we have to prove it from the definitions of other relations involved.

Comment: What you write is basically correct, but somewhat sloppy. Indeed, in the title you write $U,V$ *finite*, but then you index them over $\Bbb{N}$ (although I think that the statement is valid even for $U,V$ countable). Furthermore, $U$ and $V$ may very well have different cardinalities, so $\operatorname{span}(U)+\operatorname{span}(V) \neq \{\sum_{i = 1}^k(a_iu_i+b_iv_i)\}$ in general.

Comment: @A.P. You can define it as the smallest blah blah blah...

Comment: I see. Thanks. I have only asked 2 questions so far. Can you please, see my other question and tell me what the problem is with that one(everything there is finite as well). I just want to see my mistakes so i can correct them.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sure, but in that case minimality would have made the proof trivial. :P

Comment: Your other question was likely downvoted because a bit too terse and somewhat confused. I know it's a long read, but you should have a look at our [guidelines](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for asking good questions. You don't have to take them as law, but following them will keep (most of) your questions from being closed and it will make it more likely to receive some good answers.

Comment: You don't need 'non-empty' _or_ 'finite' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by $\operatorname{span}(U) + \operatorname{span}(V)$ you mean the vector space
$$
\{u+v : u \in \operatorname{span}(U), v \in \operatorname{span}(V)\}.
$$
For notation's sake write $U = \{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ and $V = \{e_{n+1},\dotsc,e_{n+m}\}$. Then
$$
u+v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} a_i e_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} a_i e_i \in \operatorname{span}(U \cup V).
$$
Reading the equation from left to right shows that $\operatorname{span}(U \cup V) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(U) + \operatorname{span}(V)$, too.

Comment: @ A.P. I am sorry, we didnt cover vector spaces yet, so I am not sure what that is. One of the definitions I am using: let $A, B$ be sets. Then $A + B = \{x: x = a + b; a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Comment: That's the same set, don't worry. I think that you did cover them, though, even if your professor may not have defined them formally, yet: $\operatorname{span}$ wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: We are studying from this book: http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Introduction-Linear-Algebra/dp/1439800405/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452038804&sr=8-1&keywords=ricardo+henry Just completed 1.3. Vector Spaces are in chapter 5 whatever they are :)